# Get-Content with argument -Tail takes indefinite time

Tags: powershell, hexdump

When I execute `Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -encoding String -literalpath "D:\file"` on a file, it dumps the hex content within a minute, but when I execute `Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -tail 1 -encoding String -literalpath "D:\file"`,  Powershell doesn't give any output, even after 30 minutes. Here is [the link to the file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aoy94YsQZODbhEx4LVsQxDpZfNmm). What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: Here is [another file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aoy94YsQZODbhE3OBWyZUdRBwDOP) which suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I worked around it by adding `-encoding byte` switch. You were right. Files ending with hex value of \x00 are the problem, as there is practically no tail.

Comment: You should do the honors of adding the answer. The syntax that worked is `Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -tail x -encoding Byte -literalpath "D:\file"` where x is the number of bytes you want. `-encoding String` fails as there is no tail.

Comment: No. It clarifies the problem and offers the solution as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PowerShell `Get-Content` file `nul` value with `-Encoding Byte` issue

Upon downloading the file from the link you posted and opening it with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it appears the final line has a long set of `nul` characters (see below).

[image]

With this being in the content of that file, and the syntax you were using with [Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) of: **`Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -tail 1 -encoding String -literalpath "D:\file"`** to get the content, it seems that it hoses up the PowerShell query when using the `-encoding String`.

As suggested in this post on various answers [How to remove NULL char (0x00) from object within PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863455/how-to-remove-null-char-0x00-from-object-within-powershell), it seems that the hex value of `/x00` and using [Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) with the parameter `-Encoding String` for the character set to be identified as string, it doesn't like these hex values and confuses PowerShell.

---

### Conclusion and Solution

Switching the [Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) syntax using `-Encoding Byte` for the character set to be identified as bytes appears to resolve this problem.

```
Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -tail x -encoding Byte -literalpath "D:\file"
```

> The syntax that worked is `Get-Content -ReadCount 0 -tail x -encoding
>   Byte -literalpath "D:\file"` where x is the number of bytes you want.
>   -encoding String fails as there is no tail. – [Sabyasachi Mukherjee](https://superuser.com/users/607162/sabyasachi-mukherjee)